# Change user password with one Bash command line

Tags: shell, passwords, ubuntu-16.04

I am making a program with Python 2.7, I use shell commands to create new users on Ubuntu and I want to setup the password for the new user. I use command prompt (Bash) commands to create users. Is there a command line that would change user's password just with 1 shell command? I tried:

```
echo "newpass" | passwd --stdin user1
```

but it appears the current Ubuntu 16.04 version I have doesn't have the `--stdin` parameter anymore. And I need that after the command is executed, the password would be set, I would not need to retype to confirm password etc (like using terminal).

Comment: This sounds dangerous.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy On what basis? :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
echo 'user:passwd' | sudo chpasswd
```

This helped me.

Comment: Well, that is basically what I suggested? And it should be vice versa, i.e.: echo 'user:passwd' | sudo chpasswd

Comment: I'll suggest changing the correct answer to @AndriyBerestovskyy 's one as he replied first and this is just a sample of his answer. In the best case, you could remove your answer and add it as an edit on his answer.

Comment: This is a (poor) copy of the earlier answer by @AndriyBerestovskyy!

Answer (score 20):

Please see the man chpasswd(8): `man 8 chpasswd`

```
The chpasswd command reads a list of user name and password pairs from
standard input and uses this information to update a group of existing
users. Each line is of the format:

user_name:password
```

Based on the man you can use:
`echo 'user:passwd' | sudo chpasswd`

Comment: Thanks for digging out the MAN page. I never knew this was possible.

Answer (score 4):

Kindly try below one one-liner command for user & password creation

```
useradd himanshi ; echo -e "1234\n1234" | passwd himanshi
```

Comment: above trick is also useful when need to create user with password in Ansible. command module will work here.

Comment: Can you explain why does this work? Does `passwd` only read one line at a time and keeps a record where it left off?

Comment: Hi @dtc348. no. but yes you can create in bat in different way as shown below
:: Create user
net user himanshi 1234 /add

:: Set password
echo 1234| net user himanshi *

Answer (score 1):

`sudo echo -e "<yourpassword>\n<yourpassword>" | sudo passwd <user>`

This helped me.